# How to handle it when Jquery Validate remote's url ends up giving 404 (at some time)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate plugin with django-python setup.
my code for validating form goes like this:

```
$("#quickstorecreation").validate({
rules: {
            store_name1: {
                required: true,
                remote: "/checkstorename/",
            },
messages: {
            store_name1:{
                required: "Please specify the Store Name",
                remote: "Please specify a unique Store Name.(Only Alphabets)"
            },
});
```

Issue is sometimes my remote url calls ends up as 404 call and my validation logic fails.i.e no error is raised by the plugin (i.e it fails silently).How can i handle this, i looked it into the plugin's documentation but to no avail ! Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer myself, i changed the source code for remote method to handle error.jquery validate only handles the success part of remote calling, added this and it handled failed call to url. My code goes like this:

```
error: function( response ){
                    var valid = response === true || response === "true",
                        errors, message, submitted;

                    validator.settings.messages[ element.name ].remote = previous.originalMessage;
                    errors = {};
                    message = validator.defaultMessage( element, "remote" );
                    errors[ element.name ] = previous.message = message;
                    validator.invalid[ element.name ] = true;
                    validator.showErrors( errors );
                    previous.valid = valid;
                    validator.stopRequest( element, valid );
                }
```

Comment: That is ... not what I expected :) grats anyway